# Аккаунт, или учетная запись

Tags: выбор-слов, переводы

Перевожу сайт.
У пользователя есть:

- Профиль. Там хранятся личные данные, в том числе для аутентификации.
- Аккаунт, он же учетная запись. Там хранятся всякие настройки, контакты, история деятельности на сайте.

"Учетная запись" лучше тем, что она точно существует в русском языке.
Аккаунт относительно новое, но гуглится лучше (61,100,000 аккаунтов против 8,470,000 учетных записей). Или я отстала от жизни и аккаунт официально вошел в словари?

Уместно ли использовать оба названия - аккаунт и учетная запись? Или пользователь запутается? Вы бы догадались, что это одно и тоже?

Comment: Лучше использовать одно и то же название. Для многих пользователей слово "интернет" - синоним любимой социальной сети. А уж разобраться что аккаунт и учетная запись - одно и то же будет непосильной задачей для таких пользователей.

Comment: Согласен с  Artemix, в тексте перевода лучше использовать одно название.

Comment: @Серж,  да, я забыла главное правило интерфейса - не заставлять пользователя думать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто **знаю**, что это в русском понимании - одно и то же. Не один год в этой кухне варился, да и сейчас еще иногда приходится.

Но, если подходить строго, то "аккаунт" и "учетная запись" не совсем синонимы. Войти в аккаунт - залогиниться. "Войти в учетную запись"  - в понимании стреднестатистического пользователя это скорее в **интерфейс** для редактирования данных аккаунта, а то и профиля. Можно и другие примеры разницы в значениях указать.
Так что тут в любом случае надо использовать что-то одно. Или не как полные синонимы.

Comment: "Войти в аккаунт" - это надмозговый перевод. Обычно входят на сайт, а не в аккаунт...

Comment: Нет. это не перевод. Это живая речь. https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=+%09+%22%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%22

Comment: Список официальных FAQ различных сайтов (притом зачастую переводных), найденный гуглом - не доказательство живости речи.

Comment: А вот доказывать я ни чего не собираюсь. Вы же не свое мнение ничем не подкрепили, кроме голословия.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "Аккаунт" в словари еще не вошло, но сегодня оно широко распространено и используется в официальном регламенте соц.сетей. **Аккаунт** лучше тем, что он короче, и больше подходит под термин. Тем не менее, и "Учетная запись" не будет считаться ошибкой.

См. Одноклассники. 
 ***Аккаунт Лицензиата (Аккаунт)*** – учетная запись Лицензиата, создаваемая в момент регистрации в Социальной сети, позволяющая Лицензиару идентифицировать (авторизовать) каждого Лицензиата посредством уникального логина и пароля. Логин и пароль для доступа к Аккаунту определяются Лицензиатом самостоятельно при регистрации в Социальной сети и могут быть изменены им в порядке, описанном в настоящем Соглашении или разделе «Помощь» Сайта.